# Pass property with dot notation(sometimes) to function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a function that is looking through a specified collection and highlighting the checkboxes for the items that are present in that collection.

```
function highlightFiltersPresentInTransactions(collection, collectionproperty, child) {
    var found = false;

    angular.forEach(collection, function (filterType) {
        if (scope.vm.transactions) {
            found = scope.vm.transactions.filter(function (obj) {
                if (child) {
                    return obj[collectionproperty][child] === filterType.name;
                } else {
                    return obj[collectionproperty] === filterType.name;
                }
            });
        }
        if (found) {
            filterType['has-transaction'] = (found.length > 0);
        }
    });
}
```

I'm able to call it and it correctly works like this

```
highlightFiltersPresentInTransactions(scope.filterTypes, 'target', 'type');
highlightFiltersPresentInTransactions(scope.actionTypes, 'transactionType');
```

What I would like to be able to avoid is the check whether there is a child element that needs to be checked.

I attempted to call the function as such:

```
highlightFiltersPresentInTransactions(scope.filterTypes, 'target.type');
```

Since this is a string it doesn't find the property. I also tried creating a blank target object then passing target.type without the quotes.

How can I dynamically pass in a property that might or might not have a child property to my function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about passing a function reference to the function?

```
highlightFiltersPresentInTransactions(scope.filterTypes, function(o) { return o.target.type; });
highlightFiltersPresentInTransactions(scope.filterTypes, function(o) { return o.transactionType; });
```

This can be implemented pretty easily:

```
function highlightFiltersPresentInTransactions(collection, readFn) {
    var found = false;

    angular.forEach(collection, function (filterType) {
        if (scope.vm.transactions) {
            found = scope.vm.transactions.filter(function (obj) {
                return readFn(obj) === filterType.name;

            });
        }
        if (found) {
            filterType['has-transaction'] = (found.length > 0);
        }
    });
}
```

If you don't want to do that, one way or another you'll have to split your string `target.type` into separate properties, and do it your existing way (just without the explicit parameter for `child`).

Comment: I rarely think to put functions into functions. Thank you

Comment: @JonHarding no problem - remember that ES6 makes this even simpler - `myFunc(myColl, o => o.target.type)`